# How do you clear data duplicates as you are typing?

Tags: google-sheets

We are using google sheets to manage a restaurant parking lot. Our state has a curbside only ban due to the pandemic. This is the first time I have used google sheets....On our sheet we have the guests' name and total in the first two columns. When the guests' arrive we input their parking spot number in the next column. I would like the parking spot numbers to clear if they are typed into another row for another guest. Indicating that spot 1 left and now this is a new spot 1. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Welcome. Apparently you are referring to the the autocomplete feature. Unfortunately this can't be customized but you could use data validation withe a custom formula. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? If not and still interested please let us know.

Comment: Off topic, I know, but I can't believe that your restaurant is still open for business in the middle of the pandemic. I wouldn't put too much effort into solving this, you're going to be closed very soon, and for several months - plenty of time to figure out a solution.